# jQuery table column td:nth-child()

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, css-tables

I have a table and I use this code to add a `<div class="out"></div>` inside the second column cells:

```
$(".main-vervolg .right .bottom table tbody td:nth-child(2)").append('<div class="out"></div>');
```

This div go's over the text inside the cells but I don't want that the last cell of that column get's that div inside it.

Comment: Try not to put block-level elements inside a table... it sounds like you are using it for a layout which is a big Don't

Comment: Hi John, but how shall you do this then [screenshot](http://www.dreamwire.nl/klanten/table.jpg). If an item is sold out i want to put a layer over that column.

Comment: You should be able to get the desired effect by adding a CSS class to the column in each row.  `$('tr td:nth-child(2)').addClass('sold-out')`.

Comment: That is better! I have add the class to the cell with a opacity, works great. thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector along with the [`:last`](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) selector to achieve that:

```
$(".main-vervolg .right .bottom table tbody td:nth-child(2):not(:last)").append('<div class="out">out</div>');
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/KkJ8J/)

Comment: thnx mate `nth-child(2):not(:last)` is the fix :)